# ORA-06550 line 2, column 44:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file"

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, rx-java2

I am trying to execute a SQL script from Java using some rxjava2 methods.
I have a resource file called `init_db.sql`.

Its content:

```sql
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE animals';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
/
CREATE TABLE animals (
  id        NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1),
  name      VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  amount    INT,
  CONSTRAINT animals_pk PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO animals (name, amount) values ('Cats', 10);
INSERT INTO animals (name, amount) values ('Dogs', 10);
INSERT INTO animals (name, amount) values ('Rats', 10);
```

The method where the Java code is executed is the next:

```java
public  Completable initOracleDatabase(Vertx vertx, JDBCClient jdbc) {
    System.out.println("Init Oracle Database **** executing..sql script...");
    Completable completable =
      jdbc.rxGetConnection().flatMapCompletable(sqlConnection -> vertx.fileSystem().rxReadFile("init_db.sql")
        .flatMapObservable(buffer -> Observable.fromArray(buffer.toString().replaceAll(";.*$", "").split(";")))
        .flatMapCompletable(sqlConnection::rxExecute)
        .doAfterTerminate(sqlConnection::close));
   
    return completable;
```

And this is the error that I got from the logs:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 2, column 44:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
 * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
 like like2 like4 likec between into using || multiset bulk
 member submultiset
```

and the error trace log:

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:553)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:269)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:229)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:41)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:928)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1205)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1823)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1778)
  at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:303)
```

Basically I would like to know if can I use in one only statement this SQL scriptor not? or if I am missing anything or some error code translate between SQL script and Java?

Comment: You can't run multiple statements with a single `execute()` call. You need to split up your script in individual statements, then run each one separately in a loop using `execute()`  (so it would be 5 calls based on your example script)

Comment: "if can I use in a only this SQL script all I am using or not"—This arrangement of words does not make sense. Perhaps you could have another try at explaining what you mean.

Comment: thanks @khelwood I've edited my question, let me know if it's understandable now.

Comment: so then it's needed the statements splits in different scripts although in https://livesql.oracle.com/ sql worksheet sections my script works in only one? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: livesql (like any other SQL client) will do the splitting for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing PL/SQL and SQL code in the same script.

- SQL statements can be terminated by `;`.
- PL/SQL blocks are terminated by `/` on a newline and will contain nested PL/SQL (or SQL) statements that are each terminated by `;`.

So you cannot naively split your code on `;` and expect it to work as you will incorrectly split the PL/SQL blocks.

In addition to using `;` as an SQL statement terminator, you can also use `/` on a newline; so you could rewrite your script as:

```sql
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE animals';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
      RAISE;
    END IF;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE animals (
  id        NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1),
  name      VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  amount    INT,
  CONSTRAINT animals_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
/

INSERT INTO animals (name, amount) values ('Cats', 10)
/
INSERT INTO animals (name, amount) values ('Dogs', 10)
/
INSERT INTO animals (name, amount) values ('Rats', 10)
/
```

And split the script on `\n/\n`.

Or, you can just ignore catching the ORA-00942 exception and just use SQL and continue using the `;` statement terminator:

```sql
DROP TABLE animals;

CREATE TABLE animals (
  id        NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS as IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1),
  name      VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
  amount    INT,
  CONSTRAINT animals_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO animals (name, amount) values ('Cats', 10);
INSERT INTO animals (name, amount) values ('Dogs', 10);
INSERT INTO animals (name, amount) values ('Rats', 10);
```

Or, you can create a more complicated solution that actually parses PL/SQL and SQL statements and can split the script into individual statement based on the syntax tree.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer @MT0, but I've tried to separete in one script the PL/SQL (catching the ORA-00942 exception) and the other CREATE table and insserts in another SQL script and either works successfully --> ```java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object ``` 
On the other hand if use in one SQL script with the DROP table animals... also I've got an error like ``` java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist ``` srry I am quite newbie in sql